# Scala's implicit setter and getter example from book yields compile error

Tags: scala

```
class Thermometer{

  var celsius: Float = _

  def fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32
  def fahrenheit_ = (f: Float) {
    celsius = (f-32)*5/9
  }

  override def toString = fahrenheit + "F/"+ celsius + "C"
}
```

The quoted code is an example from the book `Programming in Scala 2nd edition`. When I try compiling, I get the following error:

```
scalac Thermometer.scala 
Thermometer.scala:6: error: not found: value f
  def fahrenheit_ = (f: Float) {
                     ^
```

Does scala no longer support implicitly defined getters and setters? Is there an error in the code? Or is there a new way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code in book actually contains no space character between `_` and `=`:

[image]

Comment: It matters, because the = is part of the method name. Appending _= to a method name indicates, that it is a setter und will let you write `x.setter = value`, which will be translated to `x.setter_=(value)